# how can we create a list that contain 2 different elements - from mongo to java

Tags: java, mongodb

How do you convert this to Java?
My problem is that we have a list that contains DBObject and another list. How can we create a list that contain 2 different elements?

```
{ "$ifNull": [ {some DBObject}, [] ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
DBObject dbObject =  new BasicDBObject("$ifNull", Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("key", "value"), Arrays.asList()));
```